# Does character size affect the melee range?

Tags: path-of-exile

As the title says: does the character size increase given by Emperor's Mastery affect the melee range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. Character size is a purely cosmetic stat and does not influence melee range and collision radius.

[Statement by Mark_GGG](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/969990/page/1/1#p8232479).